# Is there an algorithm to convert Euler angles to different rotation order?

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, rotation, fbx

Unity offer a easy way to get Euler angles and Quaternion. But the angles are not correct in other 3D softwares such as 3dsmax because the order of rotation in Unity is Y-X-Z but others not. Is there a way to convert Euler angles between different rotation orders?
More details:
Actually, I need to export model in Unity as .fbx file. By using FBX SDK, I've solved the differences of coordinates between Unity and 3dsmax by calling GlobalSetting.SetAxisSystem().As the image show below:
[rotation provided in Unity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ySEci.png)

If I set the rotation data directly in fbx file,and import the fbx model to Unity:

[Rotation showed imported](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XaJbB.png)

I've check the coordinate is correct. I think the vital is Euler order which in Unity is y-x-z,but fbx not. So Unity would do some extra operation on rotation when importing.

Comment: According to the [docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion-eulerAngles.html) the order of rotations is z, x, y

Comment: The order of rotation matrices is z-x-y, so the rotation order should be y-x-z. And both cause this problem.

Comment: A crude way would be to compute the matrices for each angle, rearrange these matrices, and re-convert to Euler angles.

Comment: How to calculate the matrix(x-y-z order) by using another Euler angles(y-x-z order,Unity provide)?@meowgoesthedog This is crude but not simple.Notice that the angles attained was ordered.

Comment: The matrices themselves (given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Basic_rotations)) are simple enough. The formula to convert from a matrix back to Euler angles is also readily available (e.g. [here](https://answers.unity.com/questions/11363/converting-matrix4x4-to-quaternion-vector3.html)). Google is your friend.

Comment: Methods referenced in the web link is easy enough,but it can not solve the problem I  think. According to the article:1 Change Euler angles(y-x-z order) to matrix;2.Get Euler angles from matrix.  But the results in step.2 are y-x-z order...  @meowgoesthedog

Comment: In another word: how to get the matrix in xyz rotation order that make identical effect with the matrix in yxz rotation order?

Comment: Swapping the matrices between "steps" 1 and 2 has the effect of shuffling the axis labels. Just remember to rearrange the final Euler angle vector too.

Comment: Sorry,I don't clearly understand "Swapping the matrices between 'step'1 and 'step'2 has the effect.."  Does the matrices converted from X-Y-Z Euler or Y-X-Z Euler angles?@meowgoesthedog

Answer (score 4):

Three.js is the only open-source library (I could find) to address conversion in different rotation orders. For example, let's say you have a third-party program (e.g. your 3D modeling program) with a rotation order of **XZY** and it exports rotations as Euler angles in degrees. The conversion to a Unity rotation is

```cs
public static Quaternion XZYToUnity( Vector3 r ) {

  return  

    Quaternion.AngleAxis( r.x, Vector3.right ) *
    Quaternion.AngleAxis( r.z, Vector3.forward ) *
    Quaternion.AngleAxis( r.y, Vector3.up );
}
```

Notice that in Unity, quaternions are applied from left to right, opposite to (typically) rotation matrices. To be clear, the above code yields a rotation that, when you assign it to `Transform.localRotation`, rotates the transform first around the local X axis, then the local Z axis, then the local Y axis, in that order. See [this thread about quaternion multiplication order](https://answers.unity.com/questions/810579/quaternion-multiplication-order.html).

Now, for the other direction, you can find the correct case for your rotation order in the [Three.js Euler source code](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/src/math/Euler.js). Converting our particular case 'XZY' to C#:

```cs
public static Vector3 UnityToXZY( Quaternion q ) {

  var m = Matrix4x4.Rotate( q );   
  float m11 = m[ 0, 0 ], m12 = m[ 0, 1 ], m13 = m[ 0, 2 ];
  float m21 = m[ 1, 0 ], m22 = m[ 1, 1 ], m23 = m[ 1, 2 ];
  float m31 = m[ 2, 0 ], m32 = m[ 2, 1 ], m33 = m[ 2, 2 ];

  float x, y, z;
  z = Mathf.Asin( - Mathf.Clamp( m12, -1, 1 ));

  if( Mathf.Abs( m12 ) < 0.9999999f ) {

    x = Mathf.Atan2( m32, m22 );
    y = Mathf.Atan2( m13, m11 );
  }
  else {

    x = Mathf.Atan2( - m23, m33 );
    y = 0;
  }

   return new Vector3( x, y, z ) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
}
```

If you feed a `Transform.localRotation` to this method, it gives us back the XZY Euler angles in degrees we put in the first method (ignoring the numerical error and representational non-uniqueness of Euler angles). Formally, going from Unity quaternion to XZY and back guarantees to preserve the **orientation** in space.